# Getting screen size android with xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I was wondering if anyone knows a simple way to get the height and width of an android screen size using c# in Xamarin. I need to get the screen size so that I can use it in one of my adapter classes. I have tried using the display and the IWindowManager but without success. Any help or a point in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/device_specific/detect_screen_size/

Comment: Jason, thank you for the quick response! I have actually tried this, but when I have var metrics = Resource.DisplayMetrics; I get an error saying 'Resource' does not contain a definition 'DisplayMetrics'.

Comment: its "Resources", plural

Comment: Jason, thank you so much. My bad! haha

Comment: Jason, I have one more question that you might be able to help me with. When I scale the bitmap it works when I run deploy the apk to my Note 3 but when I deploy the apk to a Nexus Emulator the bitmap doesn't get resized. Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer that worked best for me was using

```
var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 6):

```
var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;

        height = metrics.HeightPixels;
        width = metrics.WidthPixels;
```

Answer (score 5):

Here a code snippet to get some info about the screen:

```
var metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
var windowManager = this.GetSystemService(Context.WindowService) as IWindowManager;
windowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(metrics);

var height = metrics.HeightPixels;
var width = metrics.WidthPixels;
var xdpi = metrics.Xdpi;
var ydpi = metrics.Ydpi;
var density = metrics.Density;
```

The only thing that I'm not sure is the casing to the IWindowManager if can be done like this or maybe you have to do something much more specific.
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For real device screen size, use [Xamarin.Essentials](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials).

The difference between this and the accepted answer is that this will give your hardware accurate numbers, but that one will give you the size with the status and navigation bar reduced.

```
var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
var realHeightInPx = mainDisplayInfo.Height;
```